# How to get ArrayAdapter adapters into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to make an app that will detect nearby discoverable Bluetooth devices, and throw all the mac addresses into a list. For reasons I don't understand, the the app crashes if I attempt to use a list to store the strings from device.getAddress().

After failing to put those addresses into a List, I gave in and used an ArrayAdapter seeing that it was used in some sample code. My thought was perhaps I could put the results into an ArrayAdapter, then extract the addresses out of it, and into myList. Still won't work. As far as I can tell, I can't use Lists without my app crashing...

The app doesn't crash when I comment out any thing to do with myList.

```
/* these are declared as class members */
//private ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter;
//private List<String> myList;
/*-------------------------------*/

private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        int position = 0;

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            myArrayAdapter.add(device.getAddress());
            //myList.add(device.getAddress()); 
            //position++;  //SO USING THIS INTEGER...

        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {             
            btnLocate.setText("Refresh Location");
            btnLocate.setClickable(true);
            //position--;
            //while(position>=0){
              //myList.add(myArrayAdapater.getItem(position).toString()); 
              //position--;
            //}
        }
    }
};
```

LogCat:

```
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND (has extras) } in com.ronnyszutu.lpf.LPFMainActivity$1@40519840
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043): at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
```

Comment: i'm... kind of a noob at this... what's a logcat and how can i get it?

Comment: Not to sound like a jerk, but [it's the first hit on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+logcat)... http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html.

Comment: Post your Exception here. Go to DDMS (**i.e Window > Show View > Other > DDMS**) and select the red log cat lines, copy and paste here.

Comment: 12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND (has extras) } in com.ronnyszutu.lpf.LPFMainActivity$1@40519840
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

Comment: 12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

Comment: 12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

Comment: 12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at com.ronnyszutu.lpf.LPFMainActivity$1.onReceive(LPFMainActivity.java:97)
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
12-02 12:01:54.472: E/AndroidRuntime(16043):  ... 9 more

Comment: i got all that putting in myList.add(device.getAddress().toString())

Comment: and then trying to put the first element of myList as my button name just to see if it worked... it crashed

Comment: uhh nevermind... I found a way around my problem... kinda cheating... but i just need to make this thing look like it works :P

Answer (score 0):

You did initialize your List before attempting to add the device address to it correct? Also, you may want to read about the Receiver lifecycle, as the developer docs discuss how long the object is valid for. [BroadcastReceiver#ReceiverLifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle)